# compute the average of values for every five seconds in python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, datetime, time-series

I have a dataset like below, Its time col is based on milliseconds.

```
pid_col ,timestamp_col ,value_col
31,2019-03-29 07:14:56.999999756,0.0
31,2019-03-29 07:14:57.250000,0.614595
31,2019-03-29 07:14:57.500000,0.678615
31,2019-03-29 07:14:57.750000,0.687578
31,2019-03-29 07:14:58.000000244,0.559804
31,2019-03-29 07:14:58.250000,0.522672
31,2019-03-29 07:14:58.499999512,0.51627
31,2019-03-29 07:14:58.750000,0.51627
31,2019-03-29 07:14:59.000000244,0.517551
31,2019-03-29 07:14:59.250000,0.51627
31,2019-03-29 07:14:59.500000244,0.509868
31,2019-03-29 07:14:59.750000488,0.513709
31,2019-03-29 07:15:00,0.513709
31,2019-03-29 07:15:00.249999512,0.518831
31,2019-03-29 07:15:00.500000,0.531635
```

How could I compute the average of values in every 5 seconds??for this dataset I should exactly compute the avg of values every five seconds... I mean values for the first 5 seconds should compute between 7:14:56 till 7:15:01 and so on for every 5 seconds.here is my code:

```
col_list = ["timestamp", "pid","value"]
df = read_csv("data.csv", usecols=col_list)
df['timestamp'] = to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit='ms')
df = df.groupby(['pid', Grouper(freq='5S', key='timestamp')], as_index=False) \
      .agg({'timestamp': 'first', 'value': 'mean'})
```

Thanks for your helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a nice library called `datetime` which is able to make operations between dates. For exemple:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, second, microsecond)
time0 = datetime(2019, 3, 29, 7, 14, 57, 500000)
print(time0)

fiveseconds = timedelta(seconds=5)
print(fiveseconds)

time1 = time0 + fiveseconds
print(time1)
```

gives the output

```
2019-03-29 07:14:57.500000
0:00:05
2019-03-29 07:15:02.500000
```

And you can make comparations between then:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

time0 = datetime(2019, 3, 29, 7, 14, 57, 500000)

fourseconds = timedelta(seconds=4)
fiveseconds = timedelta(seconds=5)
sixseconds = timedelta(seconds=6)

time1 = time0 + fiveseconds
print(time1 < (time0 + fourseconds))  # False
print(time1 < (time0 + sixseconds))  # True
```

So, for your problem:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from numpy import floor


def convert(timestr):
    """
    It receives a string, like ""2019-03-29 07:14:57.250000"
    And returns a datetime instance
    """
    date = timestr.split(" ")
    year, month, day = date[0].split("-")
    year = int(year)
    month = int(month)
    day = int(day)
    hour, minute, second = date[1].split(":")
    hour = int(hour)
    minute = int(minute)
    intsecond = int(second.split(".")[0])
    if "." in second:
        microsecond = int(floor(1e+6 * float("0." + second.split(".")[1])))
    else:
        microsecond = 0
    return datetime(year, month, day, hour, minute, intsecond, microsecond)


listtimes = ["2019-03-29 07:14:56.999999756",
             "2019-03-29 07:14:57.250000",
             "2019-03-29 07:14:57.500000",
             "2019-03-29 07:14:57.750000",
             "2019-03-29 07:14:58.000000244",
             "2019-03-29 07:14:58.250000",
             "2019-03-29 07:14:58.499999512",
             "2019-03-29 07:14:58.750000",
             "2019-03-29 07:14:59.000000244",
             "2019-03-29 07:14:59.250000",
             "2019-03-29 07:14:59.500000244",
             "2019-03-29 07:14:59.750000488",
             "2019-03-29 07:15:00",
             "2019-03-29 07:15:00.249999512",
             "2019-03-29 07:15:00.500000"]

listvalues = [0.0,
              0.614595,
              0.678615,
              0.687578,
              0.559804,
              0.522672,
              0.51627,
              0.51627,
              0.517551,
              0.51627,
              0.509868,
              0.513709,
              0.513709,
              0.518831,
              0.531635]

dt = timedelta(seconds=5)

averagevalues = []
time0 = convert(listtimes[0])
time1 = time0 + dt
counter = 0
mysum = 0
for i, v in enumerate(listvalues):
    if convert(listtimes[i]) >= time1:
        averagevalues.append(mysum / counter)
        counter = 0
        mysum = 0
        time1 += dt

    counter += 1
    mysum += v

if counter != 0:
    averagevalues.append(mysum / counter)
print(averagevalues)
```

gives the result

```
[0.5144918]
```

Therefore, if you have a bigger list of values, and bigger times, the list `averagevalues` will group the average for each `5 seconds`. In this exemple all the times were between `2019-03-29 07:14:56` and `"2019-03-29 07:15:01`, so we got only one value inside `averagevalues`